# Is this Git flow suitable to manage merges and deployments?

Tags: git, continuous-integration

We have prepared a Git flow with teammates, and I wonder if it is sustainable. We want to keep committing on both dev and feature branches. Also, we we want to avoid facing with conflicts during merging. Do you think if there is better way to manage the commits?

Currently, we are using SVN, but we want to move Git. This is one of our key concerns. It seems like this flow could have problems when reverting packages. Is there an alternative flow that would avoid this problem?

[image: schematic diagram of proposed Git flow]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing wrong IMO is this sentence:

> we want to keep committing on both dev and feature branches

If developer works on a branch he created, eg. branch `featureX` for feature X, he pushes changes ONLY to that branch, NOT TO `dev` where (as I assume) only stable code (Without errors) should be present.

Once the developer is done with the feature X (so branch `featureX` is stable), he should make pull request to `dev` branch, so co-workers can review it. After that, `featureX` should be merged into `dev` - this way the branch `dev` will grow and consist of the most recent, stable app version.

But.. `dev` can change as `featureX` is developed (some work can be merged into `dev`) and it can lead to conflicts - you will never go around this, si it must be faced - but we can minimize conflicts to resolve - the key is for every developer to merge `dev` branch every once in a while into their particular branches (like `featureX`) so the branch won't be left behind.

Comment: Hi Michal, firstly thanks for answering, actually i agree with you however there are two different team using same repository and one of them wants to keep commiting on dev. if it was possible i would push each developer to commit their changes on their feature branches.

Comment: @menethil Then what you have is not one branching strategy, but two, in the same repository, and that's unlikely to end happily. Maybe the two teams should be working in separate git repositories, and responsible for their own application / component? If that's not possible, you need someone with authority over both teams to set the rules.

Comment: Especially merge your dev branch into your feature branch _right before the pull request_. Merging into dev should be done without any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to be cautious about here.

## Avoid using common terms for uncommon things

The names you've used for your branches match those used in a lot of common workflows, and that's going to make people think they know what they're for and how to use them. If they are used in roughly the same way, that might be a good thing; but if you want to have very different rules for them, it's going to cause confusion.

## Your git workflow should reflect your development workflow, not vice versa

The version control system is a tool to help you coordinate on your work, but there are many more tools and processes needed to name that successful. You should be looking at how you want to organise your collaboration, and then deciding how the tool can help you achieve that.

The idea that "team A wants to commit to dev" takes the existence of a dev branch as a starting point, and works out how to collaborate on it, rather than taking a pattern of collaboration as a starting point, and representing it in version control.

## Everyone working in one repository needs to be collaborating on one workflow

You've mentioned that you have to teams, with different ways of working, and are trying to accommodate these by each team using the branches in different ways. This sounds like a recipe for disaster, because you don't have a good model for how these teams interact with each other.

If the teams are actually working on separate components within the repository, just go ahead and make multiple repositories, then each team can use whatever workflow they want within their own repository. This is probably less common with Subversion, which tends to represent applications, branches, and modules all in one hierarchy, but with git it's perfectly normal; there are tools out there for splitting and merging in various ways without losing history.

If there is some part of the repository that both teams collaborate on, that can be a third repository. The workflow in that repository needs to be agreed by both teams. It might be much simpler - a shared library might just have a strict "semantic versioning" requirement, and be tagged whenever a change is made. On the other hand, it might have stricter review guidelines, because changes have a wide impact across both teams.

Alternatively, maybe the two teams are genuinely working on the same components, but on different types of change - perhaps one team is responsible for major new features, and the other for smaller maintenance tasks on a stable version. In that case, your branch names and strategies can reflect that: have a "stable" branch, which is the sole responsibility of team A, and a "cutting-edge" branch that is the sole responsibility of team B. Both teams can land work onto their branch, and make releases as required, and then you decide a strategy of how team B picks up team A's changes. That might be every day, or every time team A tag a release; either way, the teams will need to work together to handle conflicts and related changes.

The other major possibility is that you have a political problem rather than a technical one: you have too many chiefs, and team A are backing one strategy while team B are backing another. In that case, somebody senior to both teams needs to decide how to proceed, and insist that both teams follow it. No workflow will suit everyone perfectly, but all agreeing on an imperfect strategy is likely to be me effective than each choosing a different strategy.